Is there a way I can retrieve PCIe device temperatures in windows?
I'm planning on doing some cooling upgrades to a X540T2 NIC - I've a spare one, and am planning on testing replacing the heat sink paste with a PTM7950 pad and wire up the fan pads for a fan. Since I have 2 cards I want to do comparative testing. While I guess I could run linux - and as shown below the lm_sensors package shows these temperatures on another system, and another card model.
geek@zimanas1:~$ sensors
enp14s0-pci-0e00
Adapter: PCI adapter
PHY Temperature:  +53.0°C
MAC Temperature:  +53.0°C

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C

(It also shows SSD temperatures but that's beyond the scope of this question).
It seems that the proset drivers do have some way to check in temperatures - via the diagnostic option in the Proset adaptor configuration utility but not actual numbers

If there's a sensor - is there some way I can retrieve this in windows?

According to HWiNFO: "it seems the Linux network stack has native support for temperature readout but Windows doesn't." https://www.hwinfo.com/forum/threads/monitoring-asus-pcie-network-card-temperature.9379/ and https://www.hwinfo.com/forum/threads/possible-to-add-wifi-card-temp-sensor-to-hwinfo-sensor-monitoring.7976/ .As you state, you could run Linux from USB without need to install.

Well yes, and that's plan B - I have a spare, modernish system that I can install linux on in storage I can use to test but its less convenient . This is just a lot easier for me since I can test a few other aspects (sound for example) at the same time. I might anyway since there's multiple bad ideas going on here.
